# Could not connect to SQL Server 2008 R2 Express

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2008r2-express

I am using Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Express, suddenly I got a error while I am trying to connect:

> TITLE: Connect to Server
>
> Cannot connect to DEBANJAN\SQLEXPRESS.
>
> ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:
>
> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified) (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: -1)

Please help me soon.

Answer (score 0):

There are many points to check to allow remote connection to SQL Server :

1. Open firewall TCP ports in inbound rules (135, 1433, 1434)
2. Check that SQL Server use the 1433 port : http://support.webecs.com/kb/a868/how-do-i-configure-sql-server-express-to-allow-remote-tcp-ip-connections-on-port-1433.aspx
3. Allow TCPIP protocols in SQL Server Configuration Manager (32 & 64 bits)
4. Enable SQL Browser in SQL Server Configuration Manager

This worked fine for me with Windows Server 2012 R2 & SQL Server 2008 R2 Express SP3.